# Good trading platform metrics

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I have never traded before so I asked around to find out which trading platform is good! I keep getting pop-ups for etoro and forex but I have also heard people complaining about them. So my question is:

What could potential  complaints be for such platforms? If you place a bet, do these platforms not execute or execute slowly or perhaps only allow few chosen companies to trade stock from which might be less lucrative? Or perhaps lock your money in?

All in all, I am keen to know what are good metrics that a platform should have so I could utilize it?

Comment: You can always check FX brokers on [forexpeacearmy](https://www.forexpeacearmy.com/forex-reviews).

Comment: @not2qubit how does it compare with forex or etorro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every platform will have some features that someone does not like about it so you will hear complaints about all of them.

If you google "Best Trading Platforms" you'll find lots of reviews that rate the features of different brokers.

If they offer a virtual trading platform, it's a good idea to demo it so you can see first hand how the platform performs as well as familiarizing yourself with it before going live.

Comment: this is soo true! people would complain about the slightest inconveniences :) I got recommended about interactive brokers, any experience with that?

Comment: alright, so accoding to you what are good metrics in your opinion?

Comment: JhonnyS - I have traded with Interactive Brokers for 20 yrs.  It's not an easy platform to learn and I find their Help Index terribly cumbersome and frustrating (the rare instance when I need to reconfigure something technical). I have complaints about tech support but I've never had a problem that they couldn't resolve. But when it comes to trading (using  hotkeys), I can place an order with 2 clicks unlike my Vanguard account (non trading) which takes about 15 steps to place an order. You might also take a hard look at ThinkOrSwim which has very good option analytics if you're into options

Comment: @gfdsal -  [Read my answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135042/how-to-pick-online-broker/135045#135045) here.  It provides a generic list of what services brokers offer.